# Jquery UI Datepicker add/remove

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to make a div display a date, and when it is clicked, to put in a datepicker and a button.  When the button is clicked, the datepicker's value is put back into the div.

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwA5f/6/) shows basically what I want.  However, when a div is no longer the active div, I want to remove the class marking it as active with the commented-out last line.  And doing so keeps the datepicker from being [removed at all](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwA5f/3/).

What's wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling `.each` in that code?

Comment: @SamDufel Found some snippet somewhere that says that's how you make sure that the following code is executed *after* the dom change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the save button is a child of `.testdiv`, so the click event on it bubbles up, re-triggering the `.testdiv` click handler. What's happening is that the save button and datepicker are being removed and then immediate re-added.

This is fixed by adding `event.stopPropagation();` to the save button click handler.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ee6ku/1/

I added a log statement to the testdiv click handler which you can see getting triggered if you comment out the `event.stopPropagation();` line.